# Data transfer from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, django

When creating a technical site, I faced the need to transfer data and save it in a file. I am making a website in Django. In models I create input data. I receive these data in HTML and, if necessary, the user changes them and JS performs the necessary calculations, the results of which are sent to the same page. It is possible to do a lot of analytical work on outgoing data (build graphs, calculate a loan, calculate various project risks). I prefer to create several pages so as not to fill one. All pages have already been built. There was a problem of this nature: On the main page, JS did his job but I do not know how to access this data on other pages. Is there a solution to write a JSON string to a file or send them to Django model (update static data). I read a lot and looked for solutions, but I could not figure it out until the end. Maybe someone knows the solution.

Thank you in advance.

If need more information, please let me know.
This is my first request for help, so please don’t be strict if I cannot ask correctly.

Comment: Your question is _very_ vague. Please explain in exact technical terms what you're trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: I do something wrong when send my comment to you using answer on my question. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a temporary or holding table in a database might be a solution. You would be able to fetch the data as needed when a new page loads.

There is probably a better solution though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I agree. I thought about that too. Record the results of calculations in the database and then read them on other HTML pages. So far I have not found a solution to how to implement this, since writing to the data bad should occur simultaneously with pressing the calculate button and there are a lot of values.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of with my limited experience is to try setting the data to variables within the view and running the calculations using python. Site looks beautiful by the way! Should be an awesome product when complete.

Comment: Thanks again! I have already done all the calculations in Python, but in the Java Script they work instantly, and in Python there is a noticeable delay. I was also thinking of switching completely to python, I have two problems regarding its application in HTML. 1. How can I use the code and its link so that the outgoing data gets into the HTML and 2. It is very convenient to draw graphics in python (I did them too), but I have no idea how to display them on the NTML page. If you could help me, I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: By the way: I tride save data using NODE.js which I have installed on PC. It works perfect when I use terminal and console, but when I add the same code into JS file where I make calculation, call this file from HTML page, it does not work. I think than NODE not possible to use as module in HTML, Django (in View) and JS code (if you dont start .js from terminal or inside NODE code). It could be I wrong.

Comment: I asked respected experts about NODE.js and received an answer that it is necessary to create a server and contact it via the API. It looks like this is not my way. I will try to solve the problem using the Django model.